# Google Maps draw area / shape / region and export as latitude longitude

Tags: google-maps, draw, shapes, area, region

I need a Google Map with marked up areas with different colors.

**GADM data**

The first article I came across was this one:
https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/830/how-to-highlight-an-area-city-state-or-country-in-google-maps-with-javascript

It links to this service for getting coordinates:
https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html

The problem is that there are too many points so it would end up with 3MB for an embedded map.

**Google Maps draw**

Then I tried Google Maps service to draw a shape. While it works, I could not find any export function to get the longitude and latitude.

https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1IlydZDXB-tkN8K8pAR57BRFqBOTv3c8z&ll=59.681023024095936%2C18.40997752499993&z=9

### Question

How can I draw an area on a map and then get longitude and latitude for the points? On Google Maps, a tool or something else does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem very differently. I simply used an svg file of just the country and highlighted areas there.

I used this site:
https://simplemaps.com/custom/country